# Why is the application not visible from user account?

Tags: windows-7, utorrent

I have two accounts on my Win7 computer: "admin" and "user". I use "admin" account and my wife uses "user" account.

There is an application (uTorrent) that I have installed on my PC. I can see it in "Start" menu and I can launch it successfully. However, from "user" account this application is invisible and, moreover, it does not offer to be launched when my wife clicks on .torrent file.

I guess I have installed uTorrent "for me only" or whatsoever. However, I want it to be accessible from "user account". How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

The program has been installed only for the one user profile.  You will need to install it again on the other user profile as well.  Some programs offer the option to install it for all users or just the currently logged on user.  In a case such as this you need to choose the all user option.

> uTorrent runs in a user context, to make it run for every user you
>   will have to move the installation and settings into  a directory you
>   make in "Program Files", set the download and .torrent store directory
>   in a 'public' location, edit the registry to make it start in a
>   machine context and disable UAC completely to allow it to actually
>   start without every user getting a prompt.

Information from here
[UTorrent](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=131180)